# Google sign-in webview gives blank screen after signing in

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, google-signin

I am trying to login via facebook and google in webapp, though facebook sign in works fine , i dont know what is going wrong with google sign in.
after entering google id and password i get an empty screen
here is my code-

```
    rlContainer= (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rlContainer);
    wbWebView= (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.wbWebViews);
    wbWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wbWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    wbWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    wbWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    wbWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    wbWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    wbWebView.setWebChromeClient(new PQChromeClient());

    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView view, String url) {

        String host = Uri.parse(url).getHost();
        //Log.d("shouldOverrideUrlLoading", url);
        if (host.equals(Constants.TARGET_Prefix))
        {
            if(mWebviewPop!=null)
            {
                mWebviewPop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                rlContainer.removeView(mWebviewPop);
                mWebviewPop=null;
            }
            return false;
        }

        if(host.equals("m.facebook.com")||host.equals("mobile.facebook.com")||host.equals("accounts.google.com"))
        {
            return false;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler,
                                   SslError error) {
        Log.d("onReceivedSslError", "onReceivedSslError");
        //super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
    }}

     public class PQChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog,
                                  boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
        mWebviewPop = new WebView(getContext());
        mWebviewPop.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebviewPop.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebviewPop.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
        mWebviewPop.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //mWebviewPop.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
        mWebviewPop.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebviewPop.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        rlContainer.addView(mWebviewPop);
        WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
        transport.setWebView(mWebviewPop);
        resultMsg.sendToTarget();

        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCloseWindow(WebView window) {
        Log.d("onCloseWindow", "called");
    }}
```

Can someone please explain what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you doing Google Sign-In in a webview? You really really should not do that: https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html